# dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/isl/lib/libisl.21.dylib

Tags: macos, homebrew

I'm trying to get set-up with QMK to write my own key maps for a Rama M6-c.

When running `make wilba_tech/rama_works_m6_b:default`, which is also used for the Rama M6-c, I keep receiving the following message:

> dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/isl/lib/libisl.21.dylib

within my terminal.

The error message is

> internal compiler error: Abort trap: 6 signal terminated program cc1.

I've tried the suggested commands mentioned on [QMK's website](https://docs.qmk.fm/#/faq_build?id=avr-gcc-internal-compiler-error-abort-trap-6-program-cc1-on-macos) to no success.

I've also tried upgrading homebrew, uninstalling homebrew, re-installing homebrew, fixing any warnings from homebrew's doctor command, re-running util/qmk_install.sh, upgrading node, and switching node versions.

Has anyone else experienced this issue recently or have any suggestions/fixes?

- OS: macOS Catalina
- node: 12.14.0 (default set through NVM)
- device: Rama M6-c

Answer (score 6):

Try updating the reference to isl :

```
install_name_tool -change '/usr/local/opt/isl/lib/libisl.21.dylib' /usr/local/opt/isl/lib/libisl.dylib /usr/local/Cellar/avr-gcc@8/8.3.0/libexec/gcc/avr/8.3.0/cc1
```

Answer (score 5):

This very issue is described in the FAQ:

https://docs.qmk.fm/#/faq_build?id=avr-gcc-internal-compiler-error-abort-trap-6-program-cc1-on-macos

> This is an issue with updating on brew, causing symlinks that avr-gcc depend on getting mangled.
>
> The solution is to remove and reinstall all affected modules.

```
brew rm avr-gcc
brew rm avr-gcc@8
brew rm dfu-programmer
brew rm dfu-util
brew rm gcc-arm-none-eabi
brew rm arm-gcc-bin@8
brew rm avrdude
brew install avr-gcc@8
brew install dfu-programmer
brew install dfu-util
brew install arm-gcc-bin@8
brew install avrdude
brew link --force avr-gcc@8
brew link --force arm-gcc-bin@8
```

And after that, run this command to force use v8:

```
brew link --overwrite avr-gcc@8 --force
```

It will fix your problem. At least it did for me.

Comment: Heads up this is no longer on the FAQ, and avr-gcc version 9 is installed (and works) by default

Answer (score 2):

This happened for me on a Mac while running the [musl.cc](https://musl.cc/) cross compilers. I solved it via

```
brew install isl
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't comment yet ...

You want this specifically:

```c
install_name_tool -change '/usr/local/opt/isl/lib/libisl.21.dylib' /usr/local/opt/isl/lib/libisl.dylib /usr/local/Cellar/avr-gcc@8/8.3.0/libexec/gcc/avr/8.3.0/cc1
install_name_tool -change '/usr/local/opt/isl/lib/libisl.21.dylib' /usr/local/opt/isl/lib/libisl.dylib /usr/local/Cellar/avr-gcc@8/8.3.0/libexec/gcc/avr/8.3.0/lto1
```

So that both compiling and LTO work (if you use it).